# Why is my data not recognized as time series?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, import, time-series, stata

I have daily (`day`) data on calories intake for one person (`cal2`), which I get from a Stata `dta` file.

I run the code below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
from pandas import read_csv
from matplotlib.pylab import rcParams

d = pd.read_stata('time_series_calories.dta', preserve_dtypes=True, 
                  index = 'day', convert_dates=True)

print(d.dtypes)
print(d.shape)
print(d.index)
print(d.head)

plt.plot(d)
```

This is how the data looks like:

```
0   2002-01-10  3668.433350
1   2002-01-11  3652.249756
2   2002-01-12  3647.866211
3   2002-01-13  3646.684326
4   2002-01-14  3661.941406
5   2002-01-15  3656.951660
```

The prints reveal the following:

```
day     datetime64[ns]
cal2           float32
dtype: object

(251, 2)

Int64Index([  0,   1,   2,   3,   4,   5,   6,   7,   8,   9,
            ...
            241, 242, 243, 244, 245, 246, 247, 248, 249, 250],
           dtype='int64', length=251)
```

And here is the problem - the data should identify as `dtype='datatime64[ns]'`.

However, it clearly does not. Why not?

Comment: Won't be able to help unless we see what the data looks like.  Only need a few lines.

Comment: Sure! Edited. Thanks!

Comment: Is that what the 'csv' looks like?  Sorry, 'dta'?

Comment: In the print statement, it prints "datetime64[ns]" i.e. what you are look for .... ?

Comment: No, my source is a .dta - not a .csv unfortunately. But `print.(d.head)` returns the structure shown above.

Comment: Almost, the `print.(d.index)` should return `datetime64[ns]` so it identifies as time-series

Comment: I don't know enough about the `stata` format or the `pd.read_stata` method.  But I can see that `day` is a column and not the index.  maybe try this `pd.read_stata('time_series_calories.dta', index=0, convert_dates=True)`

Comment: Hm.. I see your reason. However, it still doesn't work. strange..

Answer (score 0):

There is a discrepancy between the code provided, the data and the types shown.
This is because irrespective of the type of `cal2`, the `index = 'day'` argument
in `pd.read_stata()` should always render `day` the index, albeit not as the 
desired type.

With that said, the problem can be reproduce as follows.

First, create the dataset in Stata:

```
clear
input double day float cal2
15350  3668.433
15351   3652.25
15352  3647.866
15353  3646.684
15354 3661.9414
15355  3656.952
end
format %td day

save time_series_calories
```

```
describe

Contains data from time_series_calories.dta
  obs:             6                          
 vars:             2                          
 size:            72                          
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
              storage   display    value
variable name   type    format     label      variable label
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
day             double  %td                   
cal2            float   %9.0g                 
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Sorted by:
```

Second, load the data in Pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
d = pd.read_stata('time_series_calories.dta', preserve_dtypes=True, convert_dates=True)
```

```
print(d.head)
         day         cal2
0 2002-01-10  3668.433350
1 2002-01-11  3652.249756
2 2002-01-12  3647.866211
3 2002-01-13  3646.684326
4 2002-01-14  3661.941406
5 2002-01-15  3656.951660

print(d.dtypes)
day     datetime64[ns]
cal2           float32
dtype: object

print(d.shape)
(6, 2)

print(d.index)
Int64Index([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], dtype='int64')
```

In order to change the index as desired, you can use `pd.set_index()`:

```
d = d.set_index('day')

print(d.head)

                   cal2
day                    
2002-01-10  3668.433350
2002-01-11  3652.249756
2002-01-12  3647.866211
2002-01-13  3646.684326
2002-01-14  3661.941406
2002-01-15  3656.951660

print(d.index)
DatetimeIndex(['2002-01-10', '2002-01-11', '2002-01-12', '2002-01-13',
               '2002-01-14', '2002-01-15'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='day', freq=None)
```

If `day` is a string in the Stata dataset, then you can do the following:

```
d['day'] = pd.to_datetime(d.day)
d = d.set_index('day')
```

Comment: Rachel, my answer provides a direct solution to your question. So please consider up-voting and accepting it. Thanks.